# Unable to run AWS -Nuke

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-nuke

I am trying to run [aws-nuke](https://github.com/rebuy-de/aws-nuke) to delete all the resources.

I am trying to run command

```
 aws-nuke -c config/example.yaml --profile demo

config/example.yaml
    ---
    regions:
    - "global" # This is for all global resource types e.g. IAM
    - "eu-west-1"


    account-blacklist:
    - "999999999999" # production


    # optional: restrict nuking to these resources
    resource-types:
      targets:
      - IAMUser
      - IAMUserPolicyAttachment
      - IAMUserAccessKey
      - S3Bucket
      - S3Object
      - Route53HostedZone
      - EC2Instance
      - CloudFormationStack

    accounts:
     555133742123#demo:
        filters:
          IAMUser:
          - "admin"
          IAMUserPolicyAttachment:
          - property: RoleName
            value: "admin"
          IAMUserAccessKey:
          - property: UserName
            value: "admin"
          S3Bucket:
          - "s3://my-bucket"
          S3Object:
          - type: "glob"
            value: "s3://my-bucket/*"
          Route53HostedZone:
          - property: Name
            type: "glob"
            value: "*.zone.loc."
          CloudFormationStack:
          - property: "tag:team"
            value: "myTeam"
```

Errors screenshot below.What is this missing

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message is complaining about an alias. Try changing `555133742123#demo:` into `"555133742123" # demo:`

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes, but I have already mentioned there as prod (please check 999999999999 in account-blacklist section )

Comment: But your command-line is specifying `demo`, but the template might be in the wrong format to mark the demo account. Thus, I was suggesting to fix the formatting on `demo` to match the formatting shown in the documentation.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein `demo` is alias that we are using. please refer image 2 for that.

Comment: The error message says: "The specified account doesn't have an alias." Therefore, the problem is something to do with an alias. Your command line references `demo`, so it is likely related to that. I don't know aws-nuke, but I'm attempting to help by suggesting a fix related to the error message.  The nuke documentation shows the format as `"000000000000": # aws-nuke-example`, so I'm suggesting that you try to match that formatting for `demo` by making it: `"555133742123": # demo`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** I am an author of *aws-nuke*.

This is not an configuration problem of your YAML file, but a missing setting in your AWS account.

The [IAM Alias](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html) is a globally unique name for your AWS Account. *aws-nuke* requires this as a safety guard, so you do not accidentally destroy your production accounts. The idea is that every production account contains at least the substring `prod`.

This might sound a bit unnecessary to demand this account, but we are very passionate to not nuke any production account.

You can follow [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/console_account-alias.html) to specify the Alias via the web console, or you use the CLI:

```
aws iam create-account-alias --profile demo --account-alias my-test-account-8gmst3`
```

I guess we need to improve the error message.

Comment: Could you help me with best practices for using nuke & assume role for nuke.. I have installed it on prod and will be trying to nuke sandbox resources

Comment: Best practice is to never ever run it on prod. This is a very dangerous tool, hence the name `nuke`. For using sandbox resources, I advise to create a separate AWS account. These are free, you can easily create some with [AWS Organizations](https://aws.amazon.com/organizations/) and can even consolidate the billing.

Comment: I'm now able to execute Nuke. Below is the setup:
Nuke is installed on Acc A. In the config file Account to nuke is given as Acc B.
Created a profile for Acc B. While executing nuke we give Acc B profile. This is all working fine and nuke targets Acc B.
Can we work without creating a profile for Account B i.e create a role in Account B and give assume role access to Account A user into Account B and while executing
nuke execute with Profile A.
e.g: `aws-nuke -c config/config.yaml --profile AccountA`
With the above option nuke is trying to delete Account A. Is this possible in nuke?